# Could Not Connect to debugger issue in visual studio

Tags: c#, xamarin, build, maui

i am trying to build a application and it suddenly stops and give couldnt connect to debugger error and this happens only with one specific application and that application runs perfectly when try to build on external ,mobile device but no able to build on emulator and remaining all apps can be build on emulator. i have tried many sol but didn't workout. Can anyone help me with this issue?

i tried diferent blogs solution like enable fast debugging hyper v enable they were already enabled.

Comment: Following says it has to do with the microporcessor.  This is best explanation I found : https://localjoost.github.io/fix-for-could-not-connect-to-debugger/

Comment: Try: 1. Factory Reset emulator. 2. Delete solution’s hidden .vs folder, and .bin and .obj folders. 3. Reboot pc.

Comment: It's xamarin or maui project? And what platform did you test on? Did you try to copy the code to a new project and test?